# MYSQL variable tablename from value

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm trying to get my head around the following sql problem:

I have an `ACTIONS` table that contains the following:

```
------------------------------------
|             ACTIONS              |
|----------------------------------|
|                ID                |
|             GROUP_ID             |
|             TABLENAME            |
|             FEATURE_ID           |
------------------------------------
```

And a bunch of tables that look like this:

```
------------------------------------
|       GRASS or SAND  or ...      |
|----------------------------------|
|            FEATURE_ID            |
|             POSITION             |
|+(more columns depending on table)|
------------------------------------
```

Now the `ACTIONS`.`TABLENAME` points to a certain table (for example: `GRASS` or `SAND` or `...`)

**All** these tables have a column called `position`

I would now like to query all actions from the `ACTIONS` table with their respective `POSITION` values.
How can i tell the query to go and look for the position values in their correct tables?

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this directly as Mysql does not support joining to a variable table name.

The 2 solutions are to either generate the SQL dynamically (either in your scripting language or in an sql procedure) if you know that you will be joining to a particular link table, or building up a unioned query with one sub query per table.

```
SELECT actions.id, actions.group_id, actions.tablename, actions.feature_id, grass.position
FROM actions
INNER JOIN grass
ON actions.feature_id = grass.feature_id
WHERE actions.tablename = 'grass'
UNION
SELECT actions.id, actions.group_id, actions.tablename, actions.feature_id, sand.position
FROM actions
INNER JOIN sand
ON actions.feature_id = sand.feature_id
WHERE actions.tablename = 'sand'
UNION
........
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out!
I will have to accept that it will come down to hardcoding the tables then.

Comment: I would be entirely possible to have a MySQL procedure that looks up on one table to get a list of the tables and then dynamically builds the above type of query for all the current tables and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT` & `PREPARE` for achieving what you asked for

Check this: [MySQL Prepare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)
(search for 'how to choose the table on which to perform a query at runtime, by storing the name of the table as a user variable')

```
mysql> USE test;
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT NOT NULL);
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4), (8), (11), (32), (80);

mysql> SET @table = 't1';
mysql> SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table);

mysql> PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt3;
+----+
| a  |
+----+
|  4 |
|  8 |
| 11 |
| 32 |
| 80 |
+----+

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but in this code you have to hardcode the "SET @table = 't1'". I have to get this 't1'-value from the `ACTIONS`.`TABLENAME`-value of each row in the `ACTIONS`table.
Or am i missing the point then?

Comment: You can use it this way: 
`SET @table=(SELECT tname from actions WHERE id='1');
SELECT @table;`

Comment: You can also set a variable like this: `SELECT tname INTO @table FROM ACTIONS WHERE id = 1;`

Comment: That doesnt work for me... I'm also not sure why it would work that way, the "SET" commando only happens once. I need it to happen for each tuple/record in the `ACTIONS` table...

Comment: use a `for` loop for whole process or for forming a complex SQL statement using multiple `UNION` after getting all the table names in an array

Comment: Thank you for your help Tejesh!
After some more digging, i found this solution and it sort of works with some hardcoding.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851801/mysql-join-tables-where-table-name-is-a-field-of-another-table
I will keep playing with your solution as well because it is more versatile.